# Where exactly is the reputation scoring table?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)

I've tried to search for this and apologise if I've missed it, but I can't find the exact scoring table for reputation points.

For example, 2 for asking, 10 for correct answer, 1 for upvote, etc.

Again apologies because I'm sure it's here somewhere.

Comment: Your answer lies here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

For [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), [Super User](https://superuser.com/faq#reputation) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/faq#reputation). Currently they are all the same, but in theory at least I believe the reputation gains (and losses) could be different between the sites.